# Dell Optiplex 990 turns on and off automatically

Tags: windows-10

There's a problem about my Dell Optiplex 990 it turns on and off automatically and I cannot use it for a long period of time. It shuts down after about 15 to 20mins.

I'm using Dell Optiplex Core intel i5 PC and running  windows 10 pro.

I tried to do the turn around troubleshooting but it doesn't resolve the issue. Anyone who experience this? What did you do? Is it a hardware problem or a software?

Comment: Sounds like it's overheating, and re-starting to protect the CPU. Check your CPU and motherboard chipset temperatures with Speccy. Make sure all ventilation holes are clear from blockages, both inside and out. Check the CPU heatsink and fan aren't clogged with dust.

Comment: How can I do that? Sorry I'm not too techy. :(

Comment: Check that the temperatures are < 60°C in Speccy, if the CPU is running at 90°C then it's likely the internal cooling is insufficient. In this case, take it to a repair shop.

Comment: Alright, thank you for your answer it I'll do that. Have a nice day.